# Subclass XCTestCase results in cannot load underlying module XCTest

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xctest

I'm writing a library for testing purposes. So I need XCTest within my main target and not within my Unit-Testing target. Currently working with Xcode 9.

When I import XCTest I get the error "Cannot load underlying module for 'XCTest'".

I know the main target is not linking against the framework, but adding it into linked frameworks (required) doesn't change anything.

I've also looked into Quicks Project settings but wasn't able to find anything out of the ordinary.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under `Framework Search Paths` in Build Settings I have to add: `$(PLATFORM_DIR)/Developer/Library/Frameworks`

Then everything compiles fine :)

Answer (score 3):

This maybe a little late but what you have to do is:

The main project does not link with the XCUnit framework. You should create a separate testing target for your project, if one does not already exist, and add your test source files to that target.

1. Select your project in the Project Navigator. This will open the project's settings in the editor.
2. Click the "+" button at the bottom of the column listing your Targets.
3. If you are working on an iOS project template, select

Double check that the file in question is not in the main target but instead only the test target. Only the test target will have that framework to import.

Make sure the Target Membership is checked off for all the modules when the test framework is selected. You can view the Target Membership option by selecting View->Utilities->Show File Inspector

You've just added your tests file/class into main target and not into test target by mistake. Simple as that.

**Solution:**

1) Remove test file from "Compile Sources" list on "Build Phases" tab for main target

2) Add same file into "Compile Sources" on "Build Phases" tab for test targetIt must resolve the issue

This maybe a little late but what you have to do is: **Click on File > New > Target > iOS Unit Testing Bundle.**

And then add your tests in there. This worked for me. The problem was that I didn't select create unit tests when I created my project.

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: As I said. This is about Subclassing XCTest within my maintarget.. like Quick is doing. Not about writing tests :)

Answer (score 0):

One idea will be to include the source code of you lib in every test target.

It is not ideal, and probably not what you had in mind, but if everything else fails, this could work especially if you use git submodules or git subtrees to share the source code of your lib between test targets.